# Problema al intentar guardar una imagen en sqlite (Android studio)

Tags: android, imagen, sqlite

Buen día, estoy queriendo tomar una fotografía con la cámara y almacenarla en una base de datos sqlite en formato blob, pero al intentar guardar me tira el siguiente error.

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: incomplete input (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO registro VALUES (?,'36135737','combustible','864893033358675','0.0','0.0','00523522549@SANT@LUS ALDRO@M@36135737@B@09/02/1968@15/11/2017@206','869600046650575','sant@gmail.com','220',null,'2019-10-09 10:57:02'
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)

**El código del activity es este (la verdad tome uno que insertaba en un archivo pero quiero adaptarlo a insertar en la base de datos local)**

```
public class fotogasoil extends AppCompatActivity {
private static byte[] imagenComprimida;
private Button mboton;
private ImageView mPhotoImageView;

public static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO = 0 /*1*/;
private Uri photoURI;
private int requestCode;
private int resultCode;
private Intent data;


public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE ="";
private CameraSource cameraSource;
private SurfaceView cameraViewQR;
private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
private String token = "";
private String tokenanterior = "";
public  String textoCodigoQR ="";


public String DNI = "";
public String InfoDNI ="";
public String QR = "";
public String latitud ="";
public String longitud = "";
public String CMD = "combustible";
public String FECHAYHORA ="";
public String imeiCelular ;
public String email;
public EditText textoLitros ;


@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gasoil_dialog);

    // Views
    mboton = findViewById(R.id.AceptarGasoil);
    textoLitros = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtlitros);
    mPhotoImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageViewgasoil);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    textoCodigoQR = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    Log.e("leerQR anterior", ""+textoCodigoQR);


    //        // Listeners
    mPhotoImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        /**
         * Called when a view has been clicked.
         *
         * @param v The view that was clicked.
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("entra", "ingresa despues del clic");

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }

        }
    });

    mboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        assert extras != null;
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        getBytes(imageBitmap);
    }
}

// convert from bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    imagenComprimida =stream.toByteArray();
    Log.e("imagen", ""+imagenComprimida);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
          /* photoURI = getContentResolver().insert(
             MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
             Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(fotogasoil.this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
            */
          String ArrayDatos []= textoCodigoQR.split(",");
            Log.e ("ArrayDatosv", ""+ArrayDatos);
            DNI = ArrayDatos[0];
            InfoDNI = ArrayDatos[1];
            latitud =ArrayDatos[2];
            longitud = ArrayDatos[3];
            imeiCelular = ArrayDatos[4];
            email = ArrayDatos[5];
            QR=ArrayDatos[6];

            InsertarDatos(CMD,DNI,QR, latitud, longitud, InfoDNI, email, imeiCelular,imagenComprimida);
            Log.e("valor file", ""+photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
          //  startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp;
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
   String mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();


    return image;
}

public void InsertarDatos (String CMD, String DNI,String QR, String latitud, String longitud, String InfoDNI, String email, String imeiCelular, byte[] imagenComprimida){
    String CantidadLitros = textoLitros.getText().toString();
    DateFormat df = new DateFormat();
    df.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", new Date());
    FECHAYHORA = (String) df.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", new Date());
    CreaBaseDeDatos dbHelper = new CreaBaseDeDatos(fotogasoil.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();



         db.execSQL("INSERT INTO registro ('dni', 'cmd', 'imei','latitud','longitud','adicional','imeicelular','email','cantidadLitros','imagenComprimida','fechayhora') VALUES ('"+ this.DNI +"','"+ this.CMD +"','"+ this.QR +"','"+ this.latitud +"','"+ this.longitud +"','"+ InfoDNI +"','"+this.imeiCelular+"','"+this.email+"',"+CantidadLitros+",'"+imagenComprimida+"','"+FECHAYHORA+"'");

    db.close();
}

}
```

**Y esta es el activity donde creo la base de datos e intento insertar.**

```
public class CreaBaseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DB_NAME = "registros";
private static final String TABLE_Users = "registro";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String IMEI = "imei";
private static final String LATITUD = "latitud";
private static final String DNI = "dni";
private static final String LONGITUD = "longitud";
private static final String ADICIONAL = "adicional";
private static final String FECHAYHORA = "fechayhora";
private static final String CMD = "CMD";
private static final String LITROS = "CantidadLitros";
private static final String TICKET = "imagenComprimida";
private static final String EMAIL = "email";
private static final String IMEICELULAR = "imeicelular";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE ="";


public  String textoQR ="";


public CreaBaseDeDatos(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Users + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + DNI + " TEXT,"
            + CMD + " TEXT,"
            + IMEI + " TEXT,"
            + LATITUD + " TEXT,"
            + LONGITUD + " TEXT,"
            + ADICIONAL + " TEXT,"
            +IMEICELULAR + " TEXT,"
            +EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + LITROS + " TEXT,"
            + TICKET + " BLOB,"
            + FECHAYHORA + " TEXT"+ ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    Log.e("Base de datos", "entro a crear la base datos");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    // Drop older table if exist
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Users);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Comment: Verifica que no te este faltando llenar una columna con un registro  como EXTRA_MESSAGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que tienes varios errores de syntaxis en el query que tienes:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO registro ('dni', 'cmd', 'imei','latitud','longitud','adicional','imeicelular','email','cantidadLitros','imagenComprimida','fechayhora') VALUES ('"+ this.DNI +"','"+ this.CMD +"','"+ this.QR +"','"+ this.latitud +"','"+ this.longitud +"','"+ InfoDNI +"','"+this.imeiCelular+"','"+this.email+"',"+CantidadLitros+",'"+imagenComprimida+"','"+FECHAYHORA+"'");
```

Intenta con esto:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO registro ('dni', 'cmd', 'imei','latitud','longitud','adicional','imeicelular','email','cantidadLitros','imagenComprimida','fechayhora') VALUES ('"+ this.DNI +"','"+ this.CMD +"','"+ this.QR +"','"+ this.latitud +"','"+ this.longitud +"','"+ InfoDNI +"','"+this.imeiCelular+"','"+this.email+"','"+CantidadLitros+"','"+imagenComprimida+"','"+FECHAYHORA+"')");
```

Para agregar la imagen puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
public void InsertarDatos (String CMD, String DNI,String QR, String latitud, String longitud, String InfoDNI, String email, String imeiCelular, byte[] imagenComprimida){
        String CantidadLitros = textoLitros.getText().toString();
        DateFormat df = new DateFormat();
        df.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", new Date());
        FECHAYHORA = (String) df.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", new Date());
        DAO dbHelper = new DAO(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();

        valores.put("dni", DNI);
        valores.put("CMD", CMD);
        valores.put("imei", QR);
        valores.put("latitud", latitud);
        valores.put("longitud", longitud);
        valores.put("adicional", InfoDNI);
        valores.put("imeicelular", imeiCelular);
        valores.put("email", email);
        valores.put("cantidadLitros", CantidadLitros);
        valores.put("imagenComprimida", imagenComprimida);
        valores.put("fechayhora", FECHAYHORA);

        db.insert(dbHelper.TABLE_Users, null, valores);
    }
```

Para recuperla:

```
public void getImage() {
        DAO dbHelper = new DAO(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select imagenComprimida from registro order by id desc Limit 1", null);
        Bitmap path = null;

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
                try {
                    path = convertirByteToImg(cursor.getBlob(0));
                    mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(path);

                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap convertirByteToImg(byte[] bytes) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }
```

Modifica el query y los métodos a lo que necesites

Comment: Hola Alfredo, còmo estás? el problema es al convertir bitmap a blob amigo, le saque la parte en donde envio supuestamente la foto comprimida y ahi si pude insertar los datos. Me podrias ayudar a revisar esa parte?

Comment: Se agrega actualización

Comment: Muchisimas muchisimas gracias Alfredo

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios problemas al realizar la inserción de datos, primeramente no estas insertando los valores correctos, específicamente no debes tratar de insertar "?" :

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO registro VALUES (?,...........);
```

Ya que tienes definido el primer campo como `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, no necesitas insertar este valor, ya que automáticamente se generará un valor entero incrementable.

---

Además lo más importante es insertar correctamente los valores, definiendo los campos que deseas insertar y posteriormente sus valores, corrige script:

```
INSERT INTO registro ("dni", "cmd", ...)
VALUES('"+ this.DNI +"','"+ this.CMD +"', ...);
```

recuerda también que los valores que no son definidos como `TEXT`, no deben estar definidos entre comillas:

```
...+",'"+imagenComprimida+"','"+...
```

declara solo la variable

```
...+","+imagenComprimida+",'"+...
```

Comment: @Luis si, define los campos que serán insertados, el primero "id", no es necesario definirlo.

Comment: ahi modifico la publicación pero ahi modifique lo que sugeris y me tira el siguiente error (/SQLiteLog: (1) incomplete input)        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO registro ('dni', 'cmd', 'imei','latitud','longitud','adicional','imeicelular','email','cantidadLitros','imagenComprimida','fechayhora') VALUES ('"+ this.DNI +"','"+ this.CMD +"','"+ this.QR +"','"+ this.latitud +"','"+ this.longitud +"','"+ InfoDNI +"','"+this.imeiCelular+"','"+this.email+"',"+CantidadLitros+",'"+imagenComprimida+"','"+FECHAYHORA+"'");

Comment: os valores que no son definidos como TEXT, no deben estar definidos entre comillas, debe ser: ...+","+imagenComprimida+",'"+...

Comment: Será que estoy haciendo mal la conversión a blob de la imagen?  Eso me sale ahora unrecognized token: "[B@5f1b5b8,'2019-10-09 13:10:53'" (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):

Comment: el problema es al convertir bitmap a blob amigo, le saque la parte en donde envio supuestamente la foto comprimida y ahi si pude insertar los datos. Me podrias ayudar a revisar esa parte?